# How to create a distinct id in access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I need help with a Microsoft Access issue,

I have the following ID data,

```
ID 
AAA   
BBB   
BBB   
CCC   
DDD
```

I need to create a new numerical ID field based on the ID.  It should look like this,

```
ID  --- NewID
AAA ---   1
BBB ---   2
BBB ---   2
CCC ---   3
DDD ---   4
```

Comment: Do you intend to store `NewID` somewhere, or compute it dynamically each time you retrieve data?

Comment: Apparently NewID is not supposed to be unique? It looks like you want it to be more like a Rank. Does the NewID field need to be updated for all records any time a new record is inserted? Are you OK using VBA?

Comment: The new ID will need to be stored in the table and it will not need to be updated as this is a one time thing and no new data will be added to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your existing ID table `tblOldIDs`. And let's say it has one column, `ID`, with the data as you show above.

Now, run the following SQL statement:

```
create table tblNewIDs (
  NewID autoincrement primary key
, OldID long not null references tblOldIDs (ID)
)
```

This creates a new table that will contain your new IDs corresponding to your old IDs. And the table reference constraint will help enforce this.

Now run the following SQL:

```
insert into tblNewIDs (OldID)
select distinct o.ID
from tblOldIDs as o
```

Now your new table, `tblNewIDs`, is filled with mappings from your old IDs to new numerical IDs!

EDIT: the above insert query is fine if you're doing the mapping as a one-time thing. But if you need to repeat the mapping process, you can use the following query that only maps old IDs to new IDs if they haven't already been mapped:

```
insert into tblNewIDs (OldID)
select distinct o.ID
from tblOldIDs as o
where o.ID not in (
  select OldID
  from tblNewIDs
)
```